# XGBoost Classifier Evaluation Confusion on New Dataset Despite High Cross-Validation Scores

Tags: classification, xgboost, cross-validation, model-evaluations

I have built an XGBoost classifier model with 90 features, trained on a dataset containing 760k samples. I took great care to separate the labels from the features in both the training and testing datasets (2/3 for training and 1/3 for testing) and using a random seed of 0. Additionally, I preprocessed the data by clearing, transforming, and scaling it.

To account for the class imbalance in the dataset, I configured the **scale_pos_weight** parameter in the XGBoost model. During the training and validation process, I observed that the learning curves of the model indicate a very good fit, and when performing 5-fold and 10-fold cross-validation, the model consistently achieves over 95% accuracy(precision and recall both over 90+,confusion matrix is also perfect).

[image: XGBoost Classifier validation/train Log loss]
[image: XGBoost Classifier validation/train classification error]
[image: XGBoost Classifier validation/train ROC-AUC]

However, when I use entirely new validation sets that I trust, the model's performance is very inconsistent and sometimes quite poor. This discrepancy between cross-validation results and performance on trusted new validation sets is confusing me.

Could it be possible that the 760k samples I have in my dataset are not truly representative of the problem I am trying to solve? Maybe am I missing something?

If so, how can I identify potential sources of bias that might explain this behavior? Is there a way to improve the model's robustness on new, unseen data despite high cross-validation scores? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: note: confusion matrix x and y labels are changed on the plot.

Comment: Can you share what do you mean by quite poor ? currently it is not possible to see what do you mean. Also can you provide details on your dataset ? (content, sampling approach ?) I'd guess this might be a cv problem, where your c.v. design is leaky.